# CSS 3d transform-style preserve-3d Internet Explorer 11 Workaround

Tags: html, css, 3d, transformation

Hello I have the following css/html code which results in a display like this:
[image]

```css
            .container{width: 200px;left:300px;top:200px;height: 300px;position: relative;}
            #carousel{width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;perspective:400px;}
            #carousel figure{margin: 0;display: block;position: absolute;width: 200px;height: 200px;left: 10px;top: 10px;border: 1px solid black;}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(1) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,0deg);}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(2) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,40deg);}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(3) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,80deg);}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(4) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,120deg);}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(5) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,160deg);}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(6) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,200deg);}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(7) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,240deg);}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(8) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,280deg);}
            #carousel figure:nth-child(9) {transform: rotate3d(0,1,0,320deg);}
```

```html
<!doctyle html><html><section class="container"><div id="carousel"><figure>1</figure><figure>2</figure><figure>3</figure><figure>4</figure><figure>5</figure><figure>6</figure><figure>7</figure><figure>8</figure><figure>9</figure></div></section></html>
```

The above code was derived from the below css/html code which results in a display like this:

[image]

```css
.container {width: 210px;left:300px;top:200px;height: 140px;position: relative;perspective: 1000px;}
#carousel {width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;transform-style: preserve-3d;}
#carousel figure {margin: 0;display: block;position: absolute;width: 186px;height: 116px;left: 10px;top: 10px;border: 2px solid black;}
#carousel figure:nth-child(1) { transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(2) { transform: rotateY(  40deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(3) { transform: rotateY(  80deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(4) { transform: rotateY( 120deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(5) { transform: rotateY( 160deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(6) { transform: rotateY( 200deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(7) { transform: rotateY( 240deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(8) { transform: rotateY( 280deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(9) { transform: rotateY( 320deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
```

```html
<!doctyle html><html><section class="container"><div id="carousel"><figure>1</figure><figure>2</figure><figure>3</figure><figure>4</figure><figure>5</figure><figure>6</figure><figure>7</figure><figure>8</figure><figure>9</figure></div></section></html>
```

My question is how can I modify the top css/html code to result in a display like the bottom code without using **transform-style: preserve-3d**, reason being is because preserve-3d is not compatible with internet explorer 11.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The original code was taken from a tutorial on this page:
[3d Carousel tutorial](https://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/carousel.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question was that since preserve-3d doesn't exist in internet explorer 11, that I move the perspective property from the parent container(container) down to the carousel itself.

See code snipped:

```css
.container {width: 210px;left:300px;top:200px;height: 140px;position: relative;}
#carousel
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
#carousel figure
{
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 186px;
    height: 116px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#carousel figure:nth-child(1) { transform: rotateY(   0deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(2) { transform: rotateY(  40deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(3) { transform: rotateY(  80deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(4) { transform: rotateY( 120deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(5) { transform: rotateY( 160deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(6) { transform: rotateY( 200deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(7) { transform: rotateY( 240deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(8) { transform: rotateY( 280deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
#carousel figure:nth-child(9) { transform: rotateY( 320deg ) translateZ( 288px ); }
```

```html
<!doctyle html><html><section class="container"><div id="carousel"><figure>1</figure><figure>2</figure><figure>3</figure><figure>4</figure><figure>5</figure><figure>6</figure><figure>7</figure><figure>8</figure><figure>9</figure></div></section></html>
```